# Build System Raycast not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I want to create a build system as seen below. I specify a 'roundedPosition,' which rounds the mouse's position to integers, allowing me to build things only in certain locations. I also want to use raycasting to get object tags and make items red where I cannot place objects. However, this code works for some items but not for others. When I change the positions of the items, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. What could be the reason for this?

```
public GameObject prefab;
    public Camera Maincam;
    public GameObject selectedItem;

    private void Update()
    {

        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        Vector3 worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        Vector3Int roundedPosition = new Vector3Int(Mathf.RoundToInt(worldPosition.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(worldPosition.y), Mathf.RoundToInt(worldPosition.z));

        selectedItem.transform.position = roundedPosition;

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction);


        Debug.Log(hit.collider.tag);

        if (hit.collider.tag == "Ground" && hit.collider != null)
        {
            selectedItem.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedItem.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
        }
}
```

Is the method I've implemented incorrect or potentially harmful in terms of performance? Can I achieve this using a different approach while utilizing the 'roundedPosition' concept?

I am creating objects using the following code. It can detect all the objects I create, but sometimes it detects previously existing objects, and sometimes it does not.

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            UserInterface ui = MouseData.interfaceMouseIsOver;

            if (ui == null)
            {

                if (hit.collider.tag != "Item" && hit.collider != null)
                {
                     mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
                     worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
                     roundedPosition = new Vector3Int(Mathf.RoundToInt(worldPosition.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(worldPosition.y), Mathf.RoundToInt(worldPosition.z));

                    GameObject newObject = Instantiate(prefab, roundedPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                }
            }                   
        }
```

Comment: just a sidenote: There is [`Vector3Int.RoundToInt(Vector3)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3Int.RoundToInt.html) ;)

Comment: and I'm not sure tbh how exactly `Physics2D.Raycast` handles a 3D ray in forward direction of the camera you might rather have to use `ray.origin, Vector2.zero` which basically equals [`OverlapPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapPoint.html)

Comment: Or if you rather want to stick to the 3d ray you could try [`GetRayIntersection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.GetRayIntersection.html) instead

Comment: The code I added later can detect the objects I create, but it sometimes detects the ones I created previously, and sometimes it doesn't.